Is there an option that can be set for programs such as start/xdg-open/open/... to open files?
I am wondering about the existence of an option 'startprg' that is set by default depending on the OS that indicate what program to use when using a possible, hypothetical start command.
For example, if running under Ubuntu, then the default value for 'startprg' is xdg-open and therefore if I :start mytext.txt then xdg-open is used to open mytext.txt.
The user can of course set that option freely, e.g. 'set startprg=open'.
I am thinking to a mechanism similar to 'makeprg' and make.
EDIT: for example, if I am on Ubuntu, then by default startprg=xdg-open and therefore :start mytext.txt will be like :!xdg-open mytext.txt; if I run :start https://example.com then I would have something like :!xdg-open https://example.com.  If I am on macos, then by default startprg=open, and therefore :start mytext.txt will be like :!open mytext.txt and so on and so forth.
The default value of startprg switches depending on the OS. But, of course, the user can set it freely.
At the moment I have the following in my .vimrc but perhaps something builtin exists and I am just failing to find it.
if executable('cmd.exe')
     g:start_cmd = "start"
# Linux/BSD
elseif executable("xdg-open")
     g:start_cmd = "xdg-open"
# MacOS
elseif executable("open")
     g:start_cmd = "open"
endif

Through this, I could for example define a command that work no matter the OS as:
command! OpenMyText exe "!" .. g:start_cmd .. " myfile.txt"

In this way, no matter the OS, then :OpenMyText will attempt to open myfile.txt with what is specified in a hypothetical 'startprg' option.

Can you tell us more about what you call start? Do you have start command? Do you mean the viewer associated to netrw? It would be helpful if you could let us know the action you want to perform and the result you expect. It would make the question more concrete :-)

With start I  meant an hypothetical Vim command. I am going to add some example in my main question.

Your solution seems absolutely fine. In my answer I explains how the builtin NetRW can be use for the same. The only advantage I see is that then both your command and NetRW will use the same logic. Of course it only make sense if you are using NetRW :-)

I used netrw in the past but it never resonated with me. So no, I am not using it, unfortunately. My current setup works well, but I wonder if there is any builtin to get rid off all those if-else stuff.

Define a command (or a function) that hides the if-else stuff and concatenates the strings and you're set. Add OS-dependent stuff to run in the background so you can continue to use Vim. Technically, xdg-open will fail on a headless Linux server, if that may be an issue, you should check for a running window manager as well.

:make has makeprg, = has equalprg, gq has formatprg,etc. but there is no startprg option or anything that looks like it because there is no higher level feature :start that would require it. Frankly, doing :!open foobar.pdf or :!xdg-open foobar.pdf or :!start foobar.pdf is so easy that it doesn't warrant the extra work required for an hypothetical (and poorly named) :start command to happen.
That said, there is an infinity of reasons why a user/plugin author would want to abstract away all those platform-specific implementation details. Case in point, I use a logic similar to yours in my little vim-devdocs plugin, but to open an https:// URL in the default handler.
Adapting it to your more generic use case is easy:
function! Cmd() abort
    if exists("$WSLENV")
        return "cmd.exe /c start /b"
    elseif executable('cmd.exe')
        return "start /b"
    elseif executable("xdg-open")
        return "xdg-open"
    elseif executable("open")
        return "open"
    endif
endfunction
command! OpenMyText execute "!" .. Cmd() .. " myfile.txt"


There is a viewer action associated the gx or xf keyboard commands of NetRW:
There are different way to configure it.
You can set the viewer globally:
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer = '"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"'

You can set it by file type:
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer = "-"

function! NFH_html(filename)
  silent !'"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"' a:filename
endfunction

function! NFH_pdf(filename)
  silent !'"C:\Users\' . $USERNAME . '\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"' a:filename
endfunction

You can also call use this configuration outside the NetRW window with the following call:
:call netrw#BrowseX("my_file.txt", 0)

More information with:

:help g:netrw_browsex_viewer
:help netrw_filehandler


If you want the standard way to detect the OS in Vim I believe it is:
if has('win32')
  g:start_cmd = "start"
# MacOS
elseif has('macunix')
  g:start_cmd = "open"
# Linux/BSD
elseif has('unix')
  g:start_cmd = "xdg-open"
endif

You could be interested by the following answer.
Or as suggested by @romainl:
if !exists('g:env')
  if has('win64') || has('win32') || has('win16')
    let g:env = 'WINDOWS'
  else
    let g:env = toupper(substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', ''))
  endif
endif

if g:env =~ 'DARWIN'
  g:start_cmd = "open"
endif

if g:env =~ 'LINUX'
  g:start_cmd = "xdg-open"
endif

if g:env =~ 'WINDOWS'
  g:start_cmd = "start"
endif


No. has('unix') and has('macunix') both return 1 on macOS (built-in Vim and MacVim). See this gist for a better method.

You might also want to check for a running window manager before picking xdg-open.

It should be noted that has('macunix') still returns 0 on Linux. Nesting this check in the if has('unix') block should make the above check work. Romainl's gist has the added benefit of handling cygwin and git-bash. You would want to use start when using either of those on Windows.

Surprised by the anonymous downvote on what's essentially a good answer with a few warts :-/

Thanks for your support :-) as you said once it is a non serious game ;-)

FWIW, I downvoted this answer when it contained inaccurate information. Now that the order of the original conditional has been fixed and can revert my vote.

That make sense :-)
